# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn in two tabs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2010. I have two tabs. In each tab, I have a DataGridView (1 and 2) table with a ComboBoxColumn (1 and 2). I would like to make it so that when the user selects an index from the ComboBoxColumn1 in tab1, tab2 indicates that selection in one of the columns of that DataGridView in text form. Does anyone know how to do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the DataGridView.CellValueChanged event to catch the change in DataGridView 1 and then use that value to update DataGridView 2.